# Running Spark on Yarn, if I summit a application, which node it schedule, nodemanager or worker?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

The spark cluster and Hadoop are independent.
Nodemanager and worker node is not overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read this documentation.  It provides nice explanation of how spark is run on yarn.

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-4-x/topics/cdh_ig_running_spark_on_yarn.html